# MS Access - Dlookup criteria from selected item (listbox)

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I've seen similar questions but the provided answers couldn't solve my problem.

In access I created a form.
From a listbox you can select a name. The names are listed in the table **tNames** in the column **names_combined** (last name, given name) . In two other columns last name and given name are separated.

On the right side of the listbox you can find information about the name which will be shown in text boxes.
The goal is to show the last name from table tNames.lastname by looking for tNames.names_combined.

So I tried this:

```
=Dlookup("lastname";"tNames";"names_compined =" & Me.listbox)
```

However I just get error messages in my text box.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DLookup` requires commas not colons.

This should work assuming all the names of tables/fileds and controls are correct:

```
=Dlookup("lastname","tNames","names_compined='" & Me.listbox & "'")
```

Also make sure the actual bound field of your listbox is the combined name (by the way you code says com**P**ined).

Finally as it was pointed out in the other answer `me.something` will only work in the form itself or its VBA module. Everywhere else you need a global identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
=Dlookup("lastname";"tNames";"names_combined = '" & Forms!YourForm!listbox & "'")
```

Comment: doesn't work either :/ 
Also, Access modifies the query
`=Dlookup("lastname";"tNames";"names_combined = '" & [Me]![listbox].[Value] & "'")`
@gustav